# PowerBI - Power Query/M - Limit characters on column value and add suffix

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

**Background:** I have a column with email subject. I want these to be maximum 30 characters long. For the user to spot that i have cut the ones over 30 characters, i want to add a "..." suffix.

**Problem:** If the column content is over 30 characters, i want to remove all characters over 30, and add "..." to the end of the string.

**What i have tried:** I have added the following steps in the Power Query Editor, but it adds "..." to all lines, also the ones under 30 characters.

```
#"Extracted First Characters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column", {{"subject - Copy", each Text.Start(_, 30), type text}}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Extracted First Characters",{{"subject - Copy", "subject - short"}}),
#"Added Suffix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {{"subject - short", each _ & "...", type text}}),
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the subject column, in one step:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {{"Subject", each if Text.Length(_) > 30 then Text.Start(_, 30) & "..." else _, type text}})
```

We test if the text length is greater than 30 characters, and if so, return only the first 30 characters suffixed by "...", otherwise just return the text as is.